# For $\epsilon >0$, how to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1-e^{n\epsilon})^{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}} = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

For $\epsilon >0$, I would like to show that:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-e^{n\epsilon}\right)^{\frac{n}{n-1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-e^{n\epsilon})^{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}} = 0
$$

I can see it intuitively that $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}} \to 1$ so no matter what is under the exponent, it will be placed to the power of $1$. However, I can not see a formal way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the exponent is $n\epsilon$, not $-n\epsilon$?

Comment: (i.e., how do you define $a^x$ when $a<0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, otherwise?)

Comment: Hi, yes, that is how my term appears as when I was calculating some error bounds.

Comment: That must be a mistake, then. This is not a well-defined quantity.

Comment: Fully agree with @ClementC. I wonder a bit as there are answers given for a wrong problem. The expression is not a real number if $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post was accepted as the answer but it was not correct as Paramanand Singh states.

Comment: You seem to assume that $-1/e^{n\epsilon}\to - \infty$ but it tends to $0$. -1

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hospital's rule for the exponent, but more importantly, I think you made an error in your question. The exponent over e goes to infinity without a minus sign, and so your entire expression would go to negative infinity. With the minus sign the term involving e goes to one and then you have 1-1=0, done.

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-e^{n\epsilon}\right)^{\frac{n}{n-1}} 
$

For any $\epsilon>0$,
$e^{n\epsilon} \to \infty$
so the limit is
$-\infty$.

Comment: Slight problem if $n$ is odd as the expression is no longer real.

Comment: True. The stated problem is probably not what OP intended.